# Do paths like /profile make proper URIs? Do they violate REST? What are the implications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, uri

I'm developing an app on which regular users should have read and write permissions on their own data, while admins have read permission on everybody's.

In my design, admins can:

```
GET /users
GET /users/:id
```

But for regular users, two routing schemas came to mind. The first one being just a continuation of the first:

```
GET /users/:id
GET /users/:id/edit
PATCH /users/:id
```

and the second being another resource that is *dependent on the user that's logged in*:

```
GET /profile
GET /profile/edit
PATCH /profile
```

The advantage I see on the second approach is that the design itself doesn't allow users to change the URL and try to edit other people's records.

However, Wikipedia says:

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters that unambiguously identifies a particular resource.

and as I understand it, `/profile` doesn't fit that description since different users will see and update different records.

So, the questions are:

1. Does `/profile` make a proper URI?
2. Does it violate REST?
3. What might be other implications of such design?

Thanks <3

---

PS: probably URN is a more accurate term than URI in this situation.

Comment: Why not treat everyone as a user?  Just give each user an attribute of `is_admin`, set admins to `true` and users to `false` then check for authentication in a `before_action` on all of your admin restricted actions.

Comment: Its worth noting though that the hugely popular Devise gem uses singular routes that refer to the current user. I would worry more about not reinventing the authentication/authorization wheel.

Comment: @max I'm on devise and that's definitely being considered! Thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, it isn't really a good idea, but you will probably get away with it if you go that route.

First, it's important to recognize that one of the very powerful implications of URI that identify a resource is that you can easily share that URI (for example, pasting it into a message), and the recipient can just use it.  In the usual case, the identifier means the same thing no matter who is using it, which is to say that both clients and the server all agree what the URI refers to.

You lose some of that semantic agreement when you start experimenting with providing personalized representations of resources depending on the identify associated with the query.

A second issue is that the target-uri is an important element in HTTPs caching story; there are other condition in play, but a primary condition is whether the target-uri in the request matches the target-uri of the stored response.

So it's easy to image: Alice asks for a representation of some resource, but instead of seeing her own view of the resource, she sees a representation of Bob's view of the resource, because his was available in some public cache.

Which would be pretty awful.

That doesn't actually happen though; how do we tell Alice from Bob?  The standard answer is that we have that information in the [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header field.  HTTP caching, however, has special rules that take effect for shared caches when the request includes an authorization header.

So these rules are going to protect you unless you go out of your way to make a mess of it (for example, by using the [public cache control directive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.5)).

In summary: can you?  Yes, absolutely.  Should you...?  I eventually decided that I shouldn't.  If I need to be clever with a pronoun URI then I will use it to *redirect* to the appropriate resource, rather than leaning upon content negotiation via the authorization header.

Comment: Thanks for the _unreasonable_ response! ;)
I personally agree with you. Let's see if someone steps up with a different opinion! <3

Answer (score 1):

As with most questions, the answer is "it depends" - in this case it depends on who is the primary consumer of those URIs. If it's a user then `/profile` is perfectly acceptable since there's the additional requirement of user experience. Together with the state provided by the session cookie it uniquely represents a user. To give another example - which would be better on an e-commerce website `/basket` or `/baskets/:id`? Obviously it's the former since it allows a user to navigate directly to a URI without having to remember what their basket id is (which is likely to change over time).

Conversely, if the primary user is an API client then the format `/users/:id` may be more appropriate since that allows for a more consistent approach to coding. Though even here it may still be worthwhile providing some affordance with a URI like `/users/current`. Even if you follow the principle of [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) in an API you'll still need to get the relevant URIs to call from some singleton resource like the root path.

In general the thing to remember is that these are guiding principles and not hard and fast rules - what makes sense for your application and context may not be the same for other people's applications.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question is: "Should my route be called `/profile` based on the context of my program?"  I don't think it should.  I think you should have a base user and run something like permission levels.  Like `is_admin` or `is_moderator`.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just opinion and doesn't give insight into any of the questions.

Comment: @rogi I answer the first.  The second ones are there just to be there.  They don't really accomplish anything.